# Service Worker fazendo cache de uma aplicação asp net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, pwa, service-worker

Não consigo cumprir as especificações de progressive web apps  pois meu service worker não realiza o cache do web app.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código:

```
self.addEventListener('install', e => {
  let timeStamp = Date.now();
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open('dashboardetica.azurewebsites.net').then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll([
        '.',
        '/',
        './',
        '/Home/'
      ])
      .then(() => self.skipWaiting());
    })
  )
});

self.addEventListener('activate',  event => {
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request, {ignoreSearch:true}).then(response => {
        return response || fetch(event.request);
      })
    );
});
```